# Testing views in Django, need a hand

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-views

I'm trying to understand how django works,but I have a question in views.

With the code below

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

I understand the dictionaries but I do not know why `{'posts': posts}` is a dictionary with the same word and the value does not have quotation marks.

When I use dictionaries I use something like:

`hello = {'my_key': 'this is text', 'my_key2': 2017 }`

`{'posts': posts}`, in this example post is shown twice and the second, I mean the value does not have quotation marks.

can anyone explain me please?

Comment: Not sure why you think those are any different. The first element in quotes is the key; the second is the value.

Comment: it's exactly like the dictionaries you already know, `"posts"` is the key, an`posts` is the value, the filtered objects. The key will be a way to call your value in the template, it could also be `render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'filtered_posts': posts})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use syntax like this:

```
hello = {'my_key': 'this is text', 'my_key2': 2017 }
```

Here **key** is `'my_key'` and **value** is `'this is text'`.

But Here:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
```

In this **posts** is a variable and it has **some value**.

```
context = {'posts':posts}
```

In this case **key** is `'posts'` and **value** is the **value of posts variable**.

I hope it make sense to you. Everybody above trying to say the same thing.